# How to declare firebase pending intent as immutable in xamarin android?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, android-pendingintent

I have added firebase nuget for FirebaseInstanceIdService, FirebaseMessagingService to implement notification.
if target version is 12 or above 12 then throwing exception:

**Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'com.testapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.'**

but if target version is 11 or under 11 then push notification is working using firebase and no such exception.
code is as:

[image: MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs]
[image: MyFirebaseIIDService.cs]
[image: Added immutable flag for pending intent]
[image: menifest]
[image: exception]

can anyone help?

Comment: Are you on the Latest version of Firebase?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: @FreakyAli yes I have used latest version of firebase nuget

Comment: @Jason can you help in this?

Comment: can you please [edit] your question so that it meets the site rules?

Comment: Have you tried to update the android library to the latest version?

Comment: yes, i have updated everything i.e android sdk, firebase, menifest with compile and target versions and also firebase dependencies. Then onTokenrefresh used in messagingservice class.
now working....

Comment: Congrats.  As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems.  Thanks for your support  for xamarin. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update the options below：

1.updated android sdk ;

2.update firebase library and other nugets to the latest one;

3.try to change the compile and target versions to the newer one in manifest file;